# apache mod_rewrite: maximum number of internal redirects reached

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

i'm having a problem how to configure this one, the test site is working fine, "http://test.domain/beta/" but when we configure the domain "http://prod_domain/", pointing on the same directory, it returns an http 500 error, i checked the apache error logs and got this:

```
mod_rewrite: maximum number of internal redirects reached. Assuming configuration error. Use 'RewriteOptions MaxRedirects' to increase the limit if neccessary.
```

here is my .htaccess like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: is it possible to specify `$1` in `rewritecond`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do your condition matching against REQUEST_URI, and put a slash at the front of the match:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Also, a full and complete mod_rewrite example is available [on the CodeIgniter Wiki](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/), which includes the `%{REQUEST_URI}` bit.